# How do I output all the number of tables inmy Database but excluding the hidden and system tables?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently using the AllTables.Count to count all the tables in my DB. But it returns a big value due to the system tables and hidden tables that I use for data keeping. Is there any way to count disregardin them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `GetHiddenAttribut` to check if a table is hidden. You have to loop over the `CurrentDb.TableDefs`-collection:

The following function counts the visible tables:

```
Function CountTables()
    
    Dim cnt As Long, tbl As TableDef
    For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Not GetHiddenAttribute(acTable, tbl.Name) Then 
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ' Debug.Print "visible table found: " & tbl.Name
        End If
    Next
    CountTables = cnt
End Function
```

Comment: Just saw this Funthomas! Will definitely try this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *DCount*:

```
TableCount = DCount("*", "MSysObjects", "[Type] = 1 And [Flags] = 0")
```

Comment: I like the attempt (better than mine), but unfortunately `Flags` is pretty undocumented. AFAIK (cannot prove at the moment), you wouldn't count  linked tables, and maybe also some others

Comment: It works good! But still counts the tables i have hidden purposely. Can we also exclude that tables?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works; it does exclude hidden tables. Hidden tables has the hidden attribute making the Flag = 8 for internal tables, thus filtered out.